# How to open terminal automatically when ubuntu boots up?

Tags: boot, startup

I'm pretty new to ubuntu. I want to open terminal automatically as soon as my system boots up and opens desktop screen. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In "Startup Applications" add the program with the command `gnome-terminal`.

You can also install gnome-tweaks and go in the menu "Startup Application" where you can choose from a list the applications.